# Oracle Multiset to String

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am running a query that results in a multiset of custom Oracle type, I'd like to use the resulting multiset in another query and concatenate it with a VARCHAR2 field. I was wondering if there is a way to convert the multiset to a comma-delimited string?

What I am getting from my query is this:

```
SCHEMA.TYPE_T(SCHEMA.TYPE('D0010422'),SCHEMA.TYPE('D0010599'),SCHEMA.TYPE('D0010600'))
```

What I'd like to be able to do is include this as a string in another query:

```
D0010422, D0010599, D0010600
```

My multiset SQL:

```
SELECT CAST( MULTISET( query here) AS SCHEMA_type_t ) checks FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
create or replace type t_str as table of varchar2(100);

select 
   listagg(column_value, ',') within group (order by column_value) 
from 
   table(
      cast(
         multiset(
            select 'one' from dual
            union all
            select 'two' from dual
         ) as t_str
      )
   )
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/985ae/1)

Comment: good one, but looks like 10G doesn't have LISTAGG. Is there an alternative?

Comment: @Victor - In Oracle 10 use `wm_concat(column_value)` instead of `listagg(column_value, ',') within group (order by column_value)`